# Rvm install rubi 2.1.2 Compile from source error debian 8 x64

Tags: ruby, rvm

Rvm install ruby 2.1.2, No binary rubies available, it try compile error stack:

```
`rvm install 2.1.2`
error: ossl_ssl.c:115:69: note: in definition of macro ‘OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY’
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                 ^
Makefile:280: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jules/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.1/ext/openssl'
exts.mk:187: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jules/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.1'
uncommon.mk:180: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

[pastbin stack](http://pastebin.com/0fFcEV7Y)

Comment: Please add the error to the question, not through a link.

Comment: A add stack have got with rvm --trace install ruby-2.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Try `rvm pkg install openssl`

This should install the openssl dependencies that rvm cannot find to `$HOME/.rvm/usr`.

Then you can install ruby with rvm with the following:

```
rvm install 2.1.2 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: Thank's I solved my probleme, it's an error fix with this commit on other branch https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/patches/ruby/1.9.1/openssl-1.0.patch